# Why does vBulletin return a function in its js feed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vbulletin

If you load a vBulletin (3.6.8) js feed e.g. http://www.example.com/forum/external.php?type=js you'll get output like this:

```
function thread(threadid, title, poster, threaddate, threadtime) {
   this.threadid = threadid; 
   this.title = title; 
   this.poster = poster;
   this.threaddate = threaddate; 
   this.threadtime = threadtime; 
} 

var threads = new Array(15); threads[0] = new thread(370145, ...rest of threads in an array...);
```

What use is this function Object and what would be a safe way to evaluate this JS from javascript (Node.js), given that eval() is potentially unsafe.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    return ph.createPage(function(page) {
        return page.open("http://www.example.com/forum/external.php?type=js&forumids=1&lastpost=1", function(status) {
            console.log("opened page? ", status);
            return page.get('plainText', function(content){
                console.log(content);
                eval(content); //danger!
                console.log(thread);

                return ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load this in a `script` tag externally and then access the `threads` array.

```
<script src="/path/to/external.php"></script>
<script>
    threads.forEach(function(thread) {
        //do something with thread, has the objects listed in thread()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned I am doing this in Node.js not a browser.

Comment: Then I'd use the XML Syndication.